# Create two list with 10 instances, then a third that contains x and y 10 times

Tags: python, list, variables

I have been given a question but i dont really understand what they are asking me to do. the question they give me is:

> The target of this exercise is to create two lists called `x_list` and `y_list`, which contain 10 instances of the variables `x` and `y`, respectively. You are also required to create a list called `big_list`, which contains the variables `x` and `y`, 10 times each, by concatenating the two lists you have created.

The code that goes along is:

```
x = object()
y = object()

# change this code
x_list = [x]
y_list = [y]
big_list = x_list + y_list

print "x_list contains %d objects" % len(x_list)
print "y_list contains %d objects" % len(y_list)
print "big_list contains %d objects" % len(big_list)

# testing code
if x_list.count(x) == 10 and y_list.count(y) == 10:
    print "Almost there..."
if big_list.count(x) == 10 and big_list.count(y) == 10:
    print "Great!"
```

The outcome is ment to be:

```
x_list contains 10 objects
y_list contains 10 objects
big_list contains 20 objects

Almost there...
Great!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get more than one instance, just multiply the list:

```
x_list = [x]*10
y_list = [y]*10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = object()
y = object()

# TODO: change this code
x_list = [x]*10
y_list = [y]*10
big_list = []

z = x_list + y_list
big_list.append(z)


print("x_list contains %d objects" % len(x_list))
print("y_list contains %d objects" % len(y_list))
print("big_list contains %d objects" % len(big_list))

# testing code
if x_list.count(x) == 10 and y_list.count(y) == 10:
    print("Almost there...")
if big_list.count(x) == 10 and big_list.count(y) == 10:
    print("Great!")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as explanations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

For making 10 instance we just multiple it with `10` and then add `x_list` and `y_list` in `big_list`.

##### Code:

```py
x = object()
y = object()

# TODO: change this code
x_list = [x]*10
y_list = [y]*10
big_list = x_list + y_list

print("x_list contains %d objects" % len(x_list))
print("y_list contains %d objects" % len(y_list))
print("big_list contains %d objects" % len(big_list))

# testing code
if x_list.count(x) == 10 and y_list.count(y) == 10:
    print("Almost there...")
if big_list.count(x) == 10 and big_list.count(y) == 10:
    print("Great!")
```

##### Output:

```bash
x_list contains 10 objects
y_list contains 10 objects
big_list contains 20 objects
Almost there...
Great!
```